# WebAPI Json Formatter considers "123" as being a valid json. How to avoid it?

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following `ApiController` method

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SetData(string user,  [FromBody] JToken jsonPayload)
    {
       // 
    }
```

I'm doing some testing with malformed json values:

```
 var malformedData = new List<string>
                   {
                    @"abcd {'value' : 0}",
                    @"{'abc' : }",
                    @"{'value' : value }",
                   @"{'value' : 0} abc",
                   "abc",
                   "123"
                   };
```

For all of these values I get in the controller `jsonPayload` being null. That's fine. 
The only exception is the last string in the list `123`, and the `jsonPayload` actually contains `123`.

My Formatters config is:

```
       config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.CheckAdditionalContent = true;

        List<MediaTypeHeaderValue> unwantedTypes = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Where(type => type.MediaType != "application/json").ToList();

        foreach (MediaTypeHeaderValue unwantedType in unwantedTypes)
        {
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(unwantedType);
        }
```

What else can I set so that WebAPI considers this as a malformed json?

Comment: `123` is a valid number in json.

Comment: but if I parse it with JObject.Parse(jsonPayload); I get an excpetion

Comment: it accepts "123" as string, not number.